# github.io and css linking

Tags: html, github

I was trying to build a simple html page on github that can be used as a linking to some of my program there inside. I have build a index.html for my github.io page, so, I tried to display it but with no success. In fact the html code cannot find the css file. Any suggestions or experience in that?
Thanks
PS: the link is albz.github.io
or: https://github.com/albz/albz.github.io

several path options, local and absolute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `_site` directory the `index.html` is at the same level as `main.css`

Therefor, in the head section you should change:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/_site/main.css"></head>
```

to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/main.css"></head>
```